# Battery drains every time screen is turned on

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, screen

I just bought a new phone, it is Android 4.4.2, but it seems that it has a problem with its battery. Every time I turn on the screen, the battery drops 1%. For example, the battery is 30%. then I close the screen and turn it on again after a minute, and then in few seconds,the battery becomes 29%. It only happens when I turn on the screen, but when im using it, the battery discharge is normal. How can I fix it?

Comment: the phone model is My25 (myphone) the battery usage says the cell standby drains 46% of the battery, i understand this because i always use data connection. Thanks for the reply @beeshyams

Comment: i've noticed that Phone idle is using 26% of the battery., while screen is using 17%

Comment: I've turned off the features. How to use safe mode?

Comment: i've used safe mode but the battery still drops

Comment: i've done that before, but the battery still drops. maybe it is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Based on our chat, things which were tried are:

- Turning *off "proximity sensor" and "Smart Stay"* (to rule out malfunctioning causing battery drop h
- Checking screen usage from inbuilt battery statistics (seemed to match usage)
- Booting into safe mode and observing battery drop
- Factory reset to rule out rogue app causing this

OP has confirmed that the **Battery drop continues** as stated in the question

Being a new phone, it could either be

- ROM bug, which can be checked from user forums. If it is a reported bug add if the OEM rolls out a fix then the problem is solved
- Defective piece, which being in warranty can be exchanged (**Recommended** course of action on my opinion)

(Flashing stock again is an option but do not advise it as rooting methods, flashing tools etc may not be readily available being a lesser known phone My25 (myphone). Flashing a custom ROM for the same reason and absence of developer support , is not recommended)

Comment: Have you been able to fix it? How?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new thing in android called Smart Pixels. It is available in some custom roms like [AOSP Extended (I don't think it is available on kitkat)](https://aospextended.com/) or an android app called [Pix Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urysoft.pixelfilter)

you can choose to disable a percentage of pixels on your screen to save battery :)